# How to get url parameters when it starts with a #?

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, url-parameters

I am a beginner to **Angular JS** and **Salesforce** technology.

There is an API of salesforce which returns me the result as follows.

```
http://localhost:63342/www/index.html#/#access_token=access_token&refresh_token=refresh_token&instance_url=url&id=id&issued_at=1444216583754&signature=sign&scope=scope&token_type=Bearer
```

Here, the url parameters starts with a **hash(#)**.

If it would start with a **question mark(?)** like

```
http://localhost:63342/www/index.html#/?access_token=access_token&refresh_token=refresh_token&instance_url=url&id=id&issued_at=1444216583754&signature=sign&scope=scope&token_type=Bearer
```

then I could have simply used the `$location.search` method but salesforce does not respond it that way.

So my issue is to access the url parameters in Angular JS.

---

**EDIT:**

I used the `$location.hash` and it gave me result as follows:

```
#/#access_token=access_token&refresh_token=refresh_token&instance_url=url&id=id&issued_at=1444216583754&signature=sign&scope=scope&token_type=Bearer
```

I also tried `$location.hash.acess_token` but not working.

I want to access individual parameter, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part after the `#` is called the hash. So you can find it in `window.location.hash` or in Angular you'll find it in `$location.hash()`

Comment: Thanks!! helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use **window.location.hash** in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use script like this

```
<script>
      var app = angular.module('queryStringApp', []);
      app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
         alert("Account Number  is - "+ $location.search()['accountNo']);

         $scope.accountNo=$location.search()['accountNo'];
      });
   </script>
```

Check plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/TNX06WFx0n6p1mSLPKfP?p=preview

Comment: as I have mentioned in my url there is no '?', instead there is a '#' so this method is inapplicable.